# Нужна ли запятая перед "хоть"?

Tags: запятые

Таня, хоть довольно часто и вела себя со Светой дерзко, но в глубине души побаивалась ее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно без запятой перед ***хоть***:

*Таня **хоть** довольно часто и вела себя со Светой дерзко, **но** в глубине души побаивалась ее.*

См.:

> [**ХОТЬ / ХОТЯ (И)… А / ДА / НО**, *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_749)
>
> Запятая ставится перед второй частью союза (перед «а / да / но»).
>  *В избе **хоть и** скверно пахнет, **да** тепло, по крайней мере*... И.
> Гончаров, Обломов. *Да, он все знает, все понимает и этими словами
> говорит мне, что **хотя и** стыдно, **а** надо пережить свой стыд.* Л.
> Толстой, Анна Каренина. *Жизнь **хотя и** тяжелая, **но** не в
> пример.* А. и Б. Стругацкие, Град обреченный.